# (Eddystone) Is it possible to get the number of times an URL is received by a device without writing your own app?

Tags: ibeacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

Is it possible to get the amount of times an URL is received by a device from the proximity beacon API? I want to know what the click through ratio is of the broadcasted URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends. If you **write your own app** that scans for Eddystone-URL beacons and triggers some content (e.g., the web page itself) off of that, then naturally **you're in full control and can implement this kind of analytics**. Though it'll only apply to people which installed the app.

If you rely on **Chrome for iOS**, or the **Physical Web iOS and Android apps** to discover the Eddystone-URL beacons, then these apps **do not provide any such numbers**.

However, both Chrome for iOS and the Physical Web apps do fetch some metadata about the URL they detect, such as the page title and page description, without the user first clicking on the link. So there's a slim possibility that you could filter such requests out (they will be made by the [Physical Web Service](https://github.com/google/physical-web/tree/master/web-service), or some similar "bot"), separate them from the actual visits, and do analytics based on that. Most likely however, this "bot," or the proxying service (which is there precisely to prevent this kind of tracking, and protect the user's privacy), will also do some caching, so **you'll see fewer requests than the actual number of times the URL is received by the device.**

And finally, dropping to a lower level, a note: **most beacons are uni-directional**, i.e., they broadcast information, but **don't receive any information back**, so beacons themselves usually **can't count the number of packets on the receiving end**. (I guess you could technically use the Bluetooth "scan response" mechanism to do that, but it would require custom beacon hardware/firmware.)

Comment: Thanks @heypiotr for the very detailed answer. I was looking for the Chrome option but forgotten to specify it. However I hope this bot doesn't cache the metadata it crawls. Do you have more information about that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, it will not do this by itself.

Google's Proximity Beacon Api is a server-side system that stores metadata about beacons (location, battery level, etc) It requires you to add special client code integrated with your app to submit detection data.

Similarly, detecting Eddystone-URL beacons generally requires you to add custom code to your app to do the detections and and present the URL to the user.  (The only exception to this is for some Chrome for iOS users with the Chrome Today widget enabled, and no public system provides click through rates.)

Since your app must present the URL itself you really have to roll your own solution to this problem.

Comment: I am sorry @davidgyoung, I was looking for the tracking through the Chrome app. Still thanks for sharing your knoledge.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you should be able to achieve this by Google analytics campaign. Setup a campaign, add campaign url to ibeacon url and you should be able to check the details analytics through Google analytics.